# How to open remote file using fopen()?

Tags: php, http-status-code-403, wikipedia-api

i need to open the following url

```
$file = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Kundapura&prop=text&format=xml"; 

$fp = fopen($file, "r");
```

but i am geeting warning http request failed/ 403 forbidden

Comment: @blueshift, that is [simply incorrect](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php).  The default configuration includes a dozen different wrappers, including HTTP.

Comment: @Charles Oh, right you are. Maybe I should stick to C questions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but i am geeting warning http request failed/ 403 forbidden

The [403 error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) is coming from their server.

Chances are that you or someone on the IP address or block you are using has been aggressively banned from using the Wikipedia API.  You will need to contact a responsible admin at Wikipedia to investigate.

Comment: Note that the Wikipedia administrators have no way to check that sort of thing, you'd need to find a Wikimedia sysadmin. But fortunately, it is extremely likely that the only problem is a misconfiguration on Raghs's part.

Answer (score 5):

The default PHP user agent is blocked; see [Wikimedia's User-Agent policy](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy) for details. You can easily enough change your user agent using `ini_set` at the top of your script, like this:

```
ini_set("user_agent", "Testing for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509640");
```

Do note that the English Wikipedia forbids downloading many pages via the API (offering [database dumps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download) instead), and that automated processes that actually edit the wiki are forbidden unless [approved](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aBots/Requests_for_approval). See [their bot policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aBot_policy) for details.

Answer (score 1):

What do you need the file for? If you just need the output, you can try [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)  instead, and then load and manipulate it as a string instead of a file.

Comment: i need to parse it for application